# Invalid type in docker-compose volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I try to setup a `bind` volume in my `docker-compose` but I get the following error:

```
docker-compose up
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.web.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

My `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    #build: .
    image: fnndsc/fnndsc.babymri.org
    ports:
      - "8060:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: "bind"
        source: "."
        target: "/src/website"
    labels:
      name: "FNNDSC Web App"
      role: "FNNDSC Web App development server"
```

**Versions:**

> ```
> Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
>
> docker-compose version 1.12.0, build b31ff33
> ```

I tried many different combinations but nothing seems to work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Version 3.2 is required for the extended notation:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  web:
    #build: .
    image: fnndsc/fnndsc.babymri.org
    ports:
      - "8060:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /src/website
    labels:
      name: "FNNDSC Web App"
      role: "FNNDSC Web App development server"
```

Reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4763#issuecomment-297509279

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    #build: .
    image: fnndsc/fnndsc.babymri.org
    ports:
      - "8060:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/src/website
    labels:
      name: "FNNDSC Web App"
      role: "FNNDSC Web App development server"
```

Comment: it returns the same error...
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.web.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Comment: Version 3.2 is required for the extended notation.